# Magento Credit Card Extensions Not Working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, realex-payments-api

I installed a realex extension a couple of days ago on my Magento-based website and I've been having trouble getting it to work. We have been getting an error when trying to complete orders - it would come back with the generic popup:

> There was a problem processing your order

After contacting Realex themselves they told us that the could see we were trying to connect and that it wasn't a problem at their end.

I checked the website's error log and found this:

```
2013-05-02T08:47:50+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Ampersand_Realex_Model_Exception_Hash' with message 'Hash does not match.' in /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/community/Ampersand/Realex/Model/Adapter/Remote/Abstract.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/community/Ampersand/Realex/Model/Adapter/Remote/AuthCaptureAbstract.php(299): Ampersand_Realex_Model_Adapter_Remote_Abstract->_validateResponseHash()
#1 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Ampersand/PaymentGateway/Model/Service/Abstract.php(585): Ampersand_Realex_Model_Adapter_Remote_AuthCaptureAbstract->callbackForFinalAuth()
#2 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Ampersand/PaymentGateway/Model/Service/Abstract.php(249): Ampersand_PaymentGateway_Model_Service_Abstract->_processServiceMessages()
#3 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Ampersand/PaymentGateway/Model/Service/Abstract.php(220): Ampersand_PaymentGateway_Model_Service_Abstract->_authorizeAndCapture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '40')
#4 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Ampersand/PaymentGateway/Model/Method/DirectAbstract.php(203): Ampersand_PaymentGateway_Model_Service_Abstract->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '40')
#5 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(408): Ampersand_PaymentGateway_Model_Method_DirectAbstract->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '40')
#6 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(385): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#7 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(569): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#8 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(375): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#9 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(317): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#10 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(877): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#11 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1095): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#12 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#13 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks(Array)
#14 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#15 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#16 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#17 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#18 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#19 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
#20 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match('saveOrder')
#21 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /home/excellen/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
#23 /home/excellen/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run(Array)
#24 {main}
```

And this is the section from the file that it is telling me there is a problem in:

```
/**
 * Validate the response hash from Realex.
 */
protected function _validateResponseHash()
{
    $hash = $this->_getHelper()->generateSha1Hash(
        $this->_getConfig()->getSharedSecret(),
        $this->getResponse()->getTimestamp(),
        $this->getResponse()->getMerchantId(),
        $this->getResponse()->getUniqueOrderId(),
        $this->getResponse()->getResult(),
        $this->getResponse()->getMessage(),
        $this->getResponse()->getPasref(),
        $this->getResponse()->getAuthCode()
    );

    if ($hash != $this->getResponse()->getSha1Hash()) {
        throw new Ampersand_Realex_Model_Exception_Hash(
            $this->_getHelper()->__('Hash does not match.')
        );
    }

    return $this;
}
```

At this point though I've really reached the limit of my knowledge! I can understand that the two hashes aren't matching but what would be causing this and how could I go about fixing it?

I'm going to try and recreate the problem on a vanilla version of Magento, but if anyone can spot what is causing the problem or has had a similar problem then I'd really appreciate any help!

---

UPDATE:

I tried installing two further extensions that would handle credit card payments - the first was an alternative REALEX extension (developed by SF9) and the second was a SAGEPAY extension - both have returned errors. The following is the error log from the SagePay plugin:

```
    2013-05-02T10:15:57+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Payment has failed, please reload checkout page and try again. Your card has not been charged.' in /home/excellen/public_html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/Observer/Sales.php(127): Mage::throwException('Payment has fai...')
#1 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Model_Observer_Sales->saveAfter(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Model_Observer_Sales), 'saveAfter', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /home/excellen/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#4 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#5 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Abstract.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#6 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2155): Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#7 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
#8 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(151): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#10 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#11 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#12 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#13 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#14 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#15 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home/excellen/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/excellen/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
2013-05-02T10:15:58+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. mail() has been disabled for security reasons' in /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(454): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(506): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('david@excellent...', 'Excellent Sciss...', Array)
#4 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php(221): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('checkout_paymen...', 'general', 'david@excellent...', 'Excellent Sciss...', Array)
#5 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(528): Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data->sendPaymentFailedEmail(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote), 'Payment has fai...')
#6 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#7 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#8 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/excellen/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/excellen/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

It was running in test mode so it was not an issue related to the details that I have entered in the admin section - something seems to be wrong with the credit card payment methods (as I can successfully complete orders by choosing PayPal or other methods)

Really stuck on this one, hope someone can help! :(

---

UPDATE: The system.log output:

```
2013-05-03T08:44:20+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Mage/Realex/Model/Remote.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/excellen/public_html/app/code/local:/home/excellen/public_html/app/code/community:/home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core:/home/excellen/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-05-03T08:45:10+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Realex/Model/Remote.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-05-03T08:45:10+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Realex/Model/Remote.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-05-03T08:45:10+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'Mage/Realex/Model/Remote.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/excellen/public_html/app/code/local:/home/excellen/public_html/app/code/community:/home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core:/home/excellen/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-05-03T08:45:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:766
[2] /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:83
[3] /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:188
[4] /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[5] /home/excellen/public_html/app/Mage.php:683
[6] /home/excellen/public_html/index.php:87
</pre>
2013-05-03T08:45:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /home/excellen/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:766
[2] /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:83
[3] /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:188
[4] /home/excellen/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[5] /home/excellen/public_html/app/Mage.php:683
[6] /home/excellen/public_html/index.php:87
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to edit that code to get some logging? If so, can you print out the data and post the results here?

Add the following lines just before the `if ()` statement in the code. I'm not sure if there's a convenient logging helper you can use, so I'm just printing them to STDOUT...

```
print "Data to hash: " . $this->getResponse()->getTimestamp() . "." .
  $this->getResponse()->getMerchantId() . "." .
  $this->getResponse()->getUniqueOrderId() . "." .
  $this->getResponse()->getResult() . "." .
  $this->getResponse()->getMessage() . "." .
  $this->getResponse()->getPasref() . "." .
  $this->getResponse()->getAuthCode() . "\n";

print "Local hash: " . $hash . "\n";
print "Hash from XML: " . $this->getResponse()->getSha1Hash() . "\n";
```

(Don't print out your shared secret and definitely don't post it here!)

Owen

Comment: Hi, I tried adding that code to the file but it doesn't seem to have had any effect - there doesn't appear to be anything additional in the error logs and it causes the error message to no longer show on the front end of the site. I took a look at the system.log file and it is suggesting that there is a missing file (I'll update the first post in a moment with the log). Could this perhaps be fixed by installing the extension manually rather than using connect?

Comment: Kai, apologies for the delay. It looks like there's a missing file there all right - can you try reinstalling the plugin? Are you using the Ampersand plugin or the SF9 one?

Comment: Hi Owen - thanks for getting back to me. I'm currently using the Ampersand plugin as Realex recommended this one. I've not made much progress on it but I tried manually installing the extension this morning and it hasn't fixed the problem unfortunately. I did notice that there was a 'Dummy Payments' option and this seems to work fine and the order successfully goes through - but when using the actual bank details I get the same old message. The logs are still telling me that I'm missing `Mage/Realex/Model/Remote.php` - something im going to have a proper look at over the weekend.

Comment: Hi - I was meaning to reply to this sooner - i got this problem fixed in the end for anyone else having the same issue. In the end we were so busy looking for the cause of the problem that we missed the obvious - we had forgotten to contact Realex with the details of our website which they have now added the list of 'legal URLs' and everything is running perfectly! Thanks again Owen for your help.